# Java JInternalFrame focus

Tags: java, focus, jinternalframe

I have a class GameGUI that extends DesktopPane.  In it I have some local variables for my custom JInternalFrame windows.

For the 3 windows I've made so far, each of them is initialized and added to GameGUI the exact same way.  Each window is open/closing successfully with my custom KeyEventDispatcher class, so I know they are added and working.  However, one of the three ALWAYS opens without focus, and even after calling requestFocus(), toFront(), etc, it always shows isFocusOwner() == false.  But the other two windows work fine, appear in front, are focused, etc.  What could cause this behavior? I've tried changing the order in which they were added to no avail.

I've examined the classes and don't see any difference in the way the JIF is being initialized and displayed.  I would rather not use a workaround because I have two functional windows already.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand your problem properly, but you can try calling "setSelected" method:

```
frame.setSelected (true);
```

where frame is object of JInternalFrame subclass.